# Makefile: If string ends with other string

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to have rule that if `VAR` ends with `ENDS_WITH` it does `X` else it does `Y`.  Now, I was able to *kinda* achieve this with the following:

```
VAR := Hello, World

ENDS_WITH := rld

endswith:
ifeq ($(findstring $(ENDS_WITH)potato,$(VAR)potato),)
    @echo "$(VAR) doesn't end with $(ENDS_WITH)"
    # Do X
else
    @echo "$(VAR) ends with $(ENDS_WITH)"
    # Do Y
endif
```

However, this assumes neither string contains `potato` otherwise it will have strange behavior.  (Also it's kinda a hack)

What would be the correct way to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
$(patsubst %$(ENDS_WITH),,$(lastword $(VAR)))
```

This will expand to an empty string if `VAR` ends with the value of the variable `ENDS_WITH`, else the non-empty string.  We have to use `lastword` here because `patsubst` works on each word individually but we only care about the last one.

So:

```
endswith:
ifeq ($(patsubst %$(ENDS_WITH),,$(lastword $(VAR))),)
        @echo "$(VAR) ends with $(ENDS_WITH)"
        # Do Y
else
        @echo "$(VAR) doesn't end with $(ENDS_WITH)"
        # Do X
endif
```